# Как сделать поле формы контейнером?

Tags: html5, html-form

Некоторые примеры показывают отрицательный margin для иконки, которая просто идёт следом за полем, но можно ли само поле сделать контейнером?

[image: пример как надо]

Comment: Нельзя. . . . .

Comment: @Мир если Вам нужно изображение в самом поле ввода (без дополнительных элементов), то можете использовать свойство `background`, а также увеличить `padding` со стороны иконки.